# Looking for free ngram dataset

Tags: nlp, n-gram

I am working on correction of errors in the output of ASR systems using data mining and NLP techniques, for that i need an n-gram dictionary. I started with wikipedia ngram it give encouraging result (75% detection rate) in small test set. But when i test my solution on a large dataset, the detection rate decreased because the wikipedia ngram in not large enough to cover all english words. So i'm looking for larger ngram collected from the web, i found the "Google Web 1T 5-Grams" but my laboratory don't have enough resource to purchase it. 
If anyone already have this dataset or know how to get it for free, please help.

Answer (score 2):

The Google ngram data is available for free: http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html. It's more than a Terabyte but it's split by year, which isn't needed for most use cases, so you can probably aggregate the data into a smaller format. It's still text from books, which is different to what most users typically will feed into an ASR.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in fact I have already started the aggregation of the google books ngram dataset.